# Javascript DataTransfer items not persisting through async calls

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2, drag-and-drop, data-transfer-objects

I am using Vuejs along with DataTransfer to upload files asynchronously, and I want to allow multiple files to be dragged and dropped for upload at once.

I can get the first upload to happen, but by the time that upload is done, Javascript has either garbage collected or changed the DataTransfer items object.

How can I rework this (or clone the event/DataTransfer object) so that the data is still available to me throughout the ajax calls?

I've followed the MDN docs on how to use DataTransfer but I'm having a hard time applying it to my specific case.  I also have tried copying the event objects, as you can see in my code, but it obviously does not do a deep copy, just passes the reference, which doesn't help.

```
    methods: {
        dropHandler: function (event) {
            if (event.dataTransfer.items) {
                let i = 0;
                let self = this;
                let ev = event;

                function uploadHandler() {
                    let items = ev.dataTransfer.items;
                    let len = items.length;

                    // len NOW EQUALS 4

                    console.log("LEN: ", len);
                    if (items[i].kind === 'file') {
                        var file = items[i].getAsFile();
                        $('#id_file_name').val(file.name);
                        var file_form = $('#fileform2').get(0);
                        var form_data = new FormData(file_form); 

                        if (form_data) {
                            form_data.append('file', file);
                            form_data.append('type', self.type);
                        }

                        $('#file_progress_' + self.type).show();
                        var post_url = '/blah/blah/add/' + self.object_id + '/'; 
                        $.ajax({
                            url: post_url,
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: form_data,
                            contentType: false,
                            processData: false,
                            xhr: function () {
                                var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                                if (xhr.upload) {
                                    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (event) {
                                        var percent = 0;
                                        var position = event.loaded || event.position;
                                        var total = event.total;
                                        if (event.lengthComputable) {
                                            percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
                                            $('#file_progress_' + self.type).val(percent);
                                        }
                                    }, true);
                                }
                                return xhr;
                            }
                        }).done((response) => {
                                i++;
                                if (i < len) {

                                    // BY NOW, LEN = 0.  ????

                                    uploadHandler();
                                } else {
                                    self.populate_file_lists();
                                }
                            }
                        );
                    }
                }

                uploadHandler();
            }
        },
```

Comment: The issue isn't even specific to Vue.js... it's an issue with vanilla JS apps as well.  I made a simpler test case to reproduce the issue:  https://jsfiddle.net/rjq6b83t/1/  If you use the browser's developer tools, you'll see that the "next loop" doesn't even occur, as the DataTransfer instance seems to be dead by that time.

Comment: @Brad what about pushing promises into the array and handling them later with `Promise.All`?
https://jsfiddle.net/g5h4ajm8/2/

Comment: @TemoJr. Yeah, that works, I think the key is getting the `entry` before going off the call stack.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Once you call `await` you're no longer in the original call stack of the function. This is something that would matter particularly in the event listener.

We can reproduce the same effect with `setTimeout`:

```
dropZone.addEventListener('drop', async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.dataTransfer.items);
  setTimeout(()=> {
    console.log(e.dataTransfer.items);
  })
});
```

For example, dragging four files will output:

```
DataTransferItemList {0: DataTransferItem, 1: DataTransferItem, 2: DataTransferItem, 3: DataTransferItem, length: 4}  
DataTransferItemList {length: 0}
```

After the event had happened the state has changed and **items have been lost**.

There are two ways to handle this issue:

- Copy items and iterate over them
- Push async jobs(Promises) into the array and handle them later with `Promise.all`

The second solution is more intuitive than using `await` in the loop. Also, consider [parallel connections are limited](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network). With an array you can create chunks to limit simultaneous uploads.

```js
function pointlessDelay() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
  });
}

const dropZone = document.querySelector('.dropZone');

dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
});

dropZone.addEventListener('drop', async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.dataTransfer.items);
  const queue = [];
  
  for (const item of e.dataTransfer.items) {
    console.log('next loop');
    const entry = item.webkitGetAsEntry();
    console.log({item, entry});
    queue.push(pointlessDelay().then(x=> console.log(`${entry.name} uploaded`)));
  }
  
  await Promise.all(queue);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.dropZone {
  display: inline-flex;
  background: #3498db;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  border: 0.3em dashed #ecf0f1;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  padding: 5em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropZone">
  Drop Zone
</div>
```

Comment: Using `Promise.all` in cases of sending requests potentially can produce a problem with connections limit. For example, if user will try to upload 20 files at once, browser crash a few [overhead requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser). But of course from other side is quicker than `async ... loop`

Comment: Good point @AlexandrTovmach. In that case, the solution is to split an array into chunks and create a queue.

Comment: ...or just use `async...loop` =)

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach if you use `async` loop then you won't have the requests execute on parallel. Splitting the promises array to chunks and using `Promise.all` you get faster results and being safe not hitting any limits.

Comment: Yes, I know and I noticed that in previous comment, but splitting queue to chunks it's a bit overhead from code perspective. Just remember: "You're writing code for humans, not for machines" and you don't need to think about "faster results" before you actually have some issues with that.

Comment: what about a generator? Something along these lines, if I am understanding the problem domain and this answer correctly...
https://medium.com/javascript-scene/the-hidden-power-of-es6-generators-observable-async-flow-control-cfa4c7f31435

Answer (score 5):

Seems like context of `DataTransfer` is missing with time. My solution is to copy required data before missing and reuse it when needed:

```js
const files = [...e.dataTransfer.items].map(item => item.getAsFile());
```

Modified code from [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rjq6b83t/1/) of [@Brad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/362536/brad) with my solution:

```js
const dropZone = document.querySelector(".dropZone");
const sendFile = file => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  for (const name in file) {
    formData.append(name, file[name]);
  }
  /**
   * https://docs.postman-echo.com/ - postman mock server
   * https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ - CORS proxy server
   **/
  return fetch(
    "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://postman-echo.com/post",
    {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData
    }
  );
};

dropZone.addEventListener("dragover", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
});

dropZone.addEventListener("drop", async e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const files = [...e.dataTransfer.items].map(item => item.getAsFile());
  const responses = [];

  for (const file of files) {
    const res = await sendFile(file);
    responses.push(res);
  }
  console.log(responses);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.dropZone {
  display: inline-flex;
  background: #3498db;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  border: 0.3em dashed #ecf0f1;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  padding: 5em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropZone">
  Drop Zone
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem, and was looking to persist the entire `DataTransfer` object, not just the `items` or `types`, because my asynchronous code's API consumes the `DataTransfer` type itself. What I ended up doing is creating a `new DataTransfer()`, and effectively copying over the original's properties (except the drag image).

Here's the gist (in TypeScript): https://gist.github.com/mitchellirvin/261d82bbf09d5fdee41715fa2622d4a6

```
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem/kind
enum DataTransferItemKind {
  FILE = "file",
  STRING = "string",
}

/**
 * Returns a properly deep-cloned object of type DataTransfer. This is necessary because dataTransfer items are lost
 * in asynchronous calls. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55658851/javascript-datatransfer-items-not-persisting-through-async-calls
 * for more details.
 * 
 * @param original the DataTransfer to deep clone
 */
export function cloneDataTransfer(original: DataTransfer): DataTransfer {
  const cloned = new DataTransfer();
  cloned.dropEffect = original.dropEffect;
  cloned.effectAllowed = original.effectAllowed;

  const originalItems = original.items;
  let i = 0;
  let originalItem = originalItems[i];
  while (originalItem != null) {
    switch (originalItem.kind) {
      case DataTransferItemKind.FILE:
        const file = originalItem.getAsFile();
        if (file != null) {
          cloned.items.add(file);
        }
        break;
      case DataTransferItemKind.STRING:
        cloned.setData(originalItem.type, original.getData(originalItem.type));
        break;
      default:
        console.error("Unrecognized DataTransferItem.kind: ", originalItem.kind);
        break;
    }

    i++;
    originalItem = originalItems[i];
  }
  return cloned;
}
```

You can consume this like so, and then use `clone` in the same way you originally planned to use `evt.dataTransfer`:

`const clone = cloneDataTransfer(evt.dataTransfer);`

Comment: Beware that if you do this and you need to access the "entries" via `webkitGetAsEntry()` call, this solution won't work.