# JavaScript await inside loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to read files inside several folders and I need the whole code goes synchronously.

I converted `Callback` into `Promise` and try to `await` it:

```
function getEntries(reader) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reader.readEntries((entries) => resolve(entries))
    })
}

async function onDrop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var items = e.dataTransfer.items;
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        
        var entry = items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
        if (entry.isDirectory) {
            var reader = entry.createReader();
            var entries = await getEntries(reader);
            console.log(entries);
        }
    }
}
```

But `for` loop goes just for the first folder. What's wrong? How I should reorganize my code?

Comment: change `getEntries ` to an async function. and await for reader as well

Comment: `.webkitGetAsEntry()` is non-standard: better to use [`DataTransferItem.getAsFileSystemHandle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem/getAsFileSystemHandle)

Comment: off topic: `const getEntries = reader => new Promise(reader.readEntries.bind(reader));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The reason the `await` did not seem to work is due to how browsers handle DataTransfers in the context of async code. See this SO post for details:

- [Javascript DataTransfer items not persisting through async calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55658851/javascript-datatransfer-items-not-persisting-through-async-calls)

Here is a jsfiddle that shows the problem clearly:

- https://jsfiddle.net/kaliatech/es1nqc8v/69/

My original answer below is one way to deal handle if you actually wanted an async flow.

**ORIGINAL**

I think you meant to say that you want to read directories *asynchronously*?  If so...

As it is, the loop will await on each directory.  Instead, perhaps you want to collect the promises and continue only when all of them have resolved. Something like:

```
function getEntries(reader) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reader.readEntries((entries) => resolve(entries))
    })
}

async function onDrop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var items = e.dataTransfer.items;
    var promises = [];
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        
        var entry = items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
        if (entry.isDirectory) {
            var reader = entry.createReader();
            promises.push(getEntries(reader));
        }
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then((entries) => {
     console.log(entries);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works! So isn't possible to use `var entries = await getEntries(reader);` inside loop?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do.  Using `await` inside the loop will make the loop synchronous. It will stop at the `await` until the promise resolves.

Comment: But `await` inside loop doesn't work. It works for the first folder, but then there is no more `console.log`. Looks like the second and next promises don't resolve

Comment: Ah, now I understand the confusion. The reason is because of how file DataTransfers are handled in the browser. It's kind-of special case, and is explained in detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55658851/javascript-datatransfer-items-not-persisting-through-async-calls.  You would have to change your code to either copy the data transfer items BEFORE using async/await calls, or you would to have use the promise collection approach per my example.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I got it

Answer (score 0):

Try using for-of loop instead of for loop only if you want the previous iteration to complete before moving to next iteration. If that is not important just push every call to `getEntries` in a promise and await for that promise at end.