# FileSystemDirectoryReader.readEntries: Is there a way to read files from folder sync?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, dom-events, data-transfer-objects

FileSystemDirectoryReader.readEntries lets us read the file contents however is it is async in nature and I need to do it in a synchronous way. I have tried using async and that doesn't fit my use case as well. What I want is somewhat similiar to this. Which freezes the main thread.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/bar/foo.txt', false);  // `false` makes the request synchronous
request.send(null);

if (request.status === 200) {
  console.log(request.responseText);
}
```

I know it is bad user experience but it seems unavoidable at this point.

**The use case**

We have multiple event handlers listening to the drop event. I need to so some processing in my event handler (It's guaranteed to be the first one to receive) based on which I can decide whether the other event handlers should not process the event using `event.stopImmediatePropagation` but if I am doing stuff which is async the other handlers receive and continue to process the event even if I decide to stop propagation. **I have no control over the other handlers and cant modify their code**

I have tried stopping the propagation before my async call and dispatch the event after processing but that is proving to be difficult as the `event.dataTransfer` is empty and the other event handlers are not getting the files. Force setting the dataTransfer results in isTrusted being set to false for the event

[Javascript DataTransfer items not persisting through async calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55658851/javascript-datatransfer-items-not-persisting-through-async-calls)

Comment: Unfortunately if an api is async, there is no way to make it sync..  But did you try cloning the data like mentioned in the link you posted.

Comment: Yes I tried cloning the data and setting it using object.assign (As the event.dataTransfer doesn't have a setter) but it makes the event untrusted which affects how other event handlers treat this